# How should components interact in multithread Android application?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, oop, single-responsibility-principle

I want to make a simple Android application that must do some heavy work in background. I'm completely new to Android development and need an advice on how to design this application properly.
So, my application needs to run a server in background that accepts a client and communicates continuously with the client until the user decides to stop the server. I have a simple activity that has a button that must start and stop the server. My current thoughts are:

- Pressing the button should start a service
- The service must start a separate thread which will do all the work of the server.

I think I should create three classes: `Activity` class, `Service` class (ask the system to run the foreground `Service` so the process won't be killed if the user closes the Activity), and the `Server` class which can be `Thread` or `AsyncTask`.
The problem is that some events can occur on the Server thread that the user should be aware of, so those events must trigger some changes in the UI like showing a message. I could notify the user by manipulating the UI in the `onProgressUpdate()` method or `runOnUiThread()` but that feels off. Moreover, I think that violates the single responsibility principle as the Server does the work that is not expected. Maybe I should notify the `Service` somehow which, in turn, will do all the work to notify the user?
Moreover, I need to be able to control the server from UI somehow. So, just calling the `Service` and forgetting about it is not an option.
So, my question is how to make a good design of the application? How the components should interact with each other?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to interact with component like you have performing some task in background in the Service or get the notification from server and you want to notify or update the UI or whatever you want here in the activity or fragment in foreground like message etc..then you can use Broadcast Receiver

You need to register the receiver with specific action name in the activity or fragment where you want

And then send broadcast from service class with content or data with specific action name through intent

The event fire with action and intent on broadcast receiver onReceive method which you have declared in activity or fragment you can update the UI from here by getting the data from intent

Read The broadcast overview from android developer  official document

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts
hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in most cases, an Android device acting as a server is a bad design, since cell telephony providers currently assign private IPs and not public ones to their clients, so your listening ports will be inaccessible from the Internet.
It would only work within a LAN and connected through WiFi.

Your server task is not strictly required to be created in a Service, it can be created in other classes of the app, but you will need to create a Service if you want your server thread to not stop when the phone enters sleep mode, so to avoid this you will need to create a Foreground Service (a service that calls startForeground()) and also use a PowerManager.WakeLock.

To communicate the task with the UI thread, I recommend you to use messages, for that to work in UI thread you create an instance of a Handler derived class and overwrite the handleMessage() method.

From the server thread you can send messages using sendMessage() to the Handle derived instance and you will receive them in handleMessage() in the UI thread.

Comment: Yes, I want the server to be up even if the activity is destroyed or phone is in sleep mode. I'm planning to place a notification that will restore the activity that was used to start the server. The activity should show info about the server status (if it's running or not) so that's the reason I asked about how the components should interact. For example, if the activity is destroyed then how should I restore it? I can put info into an `Intent` but what should I do if the activity is not destroyed? The `Intent` will cause the system to create a new activity which is not what I need.

Comment: If you create a static instance of Thread or AsyncTask it will not be destroyed with the main activity. When the Activity starts if the static field is null then you create the thread. ... well, in fact a thread is not destroyed until the run () method ends, but if it were not static you would lose the reference.